# Get reference of object inside a function bind as event in js .?

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I have an constructor object like this .

```
var Cons = function(me){
  this.name= me;
  this.ele = document.getElementById("element");
  this.ele.addEventListener("click",this.fnClick,false);
}
```

and some methods extended as prototypes

```
 Cons.prototype.getme= function(){
     return this.me;
  }
  Cons.prototype.fnClick= function(){
      alert(this.getme())
  }
 var initZ = new Cons("test");
```

So my problem is when im "fcClick" is executed as a bind function **"this"** will refer to the binded HTML element , not the current instance Object,

So how can i pass the reference of "**this**" in "fnClick" ..?

jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/vqL6a/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `this.fnClick.bind(this)` or, for browsers that do not support bind:

```
var Cons = function(me){
  this.name= me;
  this.ele = document.getElementById("element");

  var self = this;
  function handler() {
    self.fnClick(arguments);
  }
  this.ele.addEventListener("click", handler, false);
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/Fy5ZV/1/ (with `getme()` returning `this.name`)

Comment: ys actualy i want it like with a self reference , but i cant bind a private fn handler , since i need to make a removeEvent in some other function, and i cant declare just public functions, its a part of a framework..

Comment: You can implement a shim for `Function.prototype.bind`, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), the *Compatibility* section.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)...

```
var Cons = function(me){
  this.name= me;
  this.ele = document.getElementById("element");
  this.ele.addEventListener("click",this.fnClick.bind(this),false);
}
```

This will guarantee that the [`ThisBinding`](http://es5.github.com/#x10.4) will be set to the calling environment's `this`.